# Send mail to two different suppliers, depending on which product the customers chooses - Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

How to send mail to two different suppliers, depending on which product the customers chooses? I added a custom field for a category, but how should I construct the function and in which file? For e.g. if user chooses product A, to send a mail to supplier A, and if they choose product B, to send a mail to supplier B.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary at the time of the order to connect to the hook confirmation in order to treat each product of the command separately.

Here is some module that could help you:

[Https://www.shopmodule.com/en/module-prestashop-for-administration/81-export-command-csvftp-by-provider-dropshipping.html](http://Https://www.shopmodule.com/en/module-prestashop-for-administration/81-export-command-csvftp-by-provider-dropshipping.html)

[Https://addons.prestashop.com/en/dropshipping/9438-dropshipping-support-services-by-mail-automatic.html](http://Https://addons.prestashop.com/en/dropshipping/9438-dropshipping-support-services-by-mail-automatic.html)

[Https://addons.prestashop.com/en/dropshipping/18721-export-command-csv-ftp-by-provider-dropshipping.html](http://Https://addons.prestashop.com/en/dropshipping/18721-export-command-csv-ftp-by-provider-dropshipping.html)

[Https://addons.prestashop.com/dropshipping/24993-dropshipping-system.html](http://Https://addons.prestashop.com/dropshipping/24993-dropshipping-system.html)

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your time, and without any modules, what is the solution?